# Display GeoTIFF with osmdroid on Android

Tags: android, osmdroid, geotiff

I want to generate a new mapsource from a GeoTIFF file to display it in osmdroid.
I Dont find any solution to convert the GeoTIFF file into the MapSource format osmdroid needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) to generate tiles from your GeoTiff. Then you need to either host these tiles for download somewhere or provide them with your app. Osmdroid allows you to provide the tiles in a zip file, although this did not work for me for very large archives.
You'll then have to add a new tile provider in osmdroid to consume your tiles.

[Here](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html)'s an example of how to provide you own tile source to osmdroid.